# How configuring Airflow service start in Ubuntu

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, azure-vm

I have Installed Airflow on my Azure Ubuntu VM. Now I want to start airflow once I start my VM.

Comment: You can add the airflow start script(s) to crontab
see here - https://askubuntu.com/a/816

Answer (score 0):

The way I have seen it done in the 6 projects I've been on is to add services to **systemd** which your Ubuntu machine should support by default.

Depending on your installation and process it's quite common to split Airflow configuration options between your VM Environment Variables, your airflow.cfg and Environment Variables declared in your **systemd** script and an Environment file.

The processes that you need to generate through **systemd** are:

1. `<path_to_airflow>/bin/airflow initdb`
2. `<path_to_airflow>/bin/airflow scheduler`
3. `<path_to_airflow>/bin/airflow webserver`

Here are some docs to get you started:

- airflow via systemd https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/run-with-systemd.html
- commands to get going https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/start.html